# Add column using equation in R

Tags: r, calculated-columns

So I'm trying to simplify a code for generating a new column in a data frame using R. My data are organized something like this (columns 1-4), and I'd like to generate column 5 (unlabeled):

```
col1__col2__col3__col4______
 t1    f1    A    20     0
 t1    f2    A    19     0
 t1    f3    A    21     0
 t1    f1    B    25     5
 t1    f2    B    25     6
 t1    f3    B    26     5
 t2    f1    A    18     0
 t2    f2    A    19     0
 t2    f3    A    18     0
 t2    f1    B    20     2
 t2    f2    B    20     1
 t2    f3    B    20     2
```

EDIT: column 5 looks like this (equation-wise). It's take the value from col4 for t1,f1, and subtracts that from t1,f1, for col3 = "A". So in row 1, it takes 20 and subtracts the very same 20. For row 4, it takes 25, and subtracts the 20 found in row 1, because both of these rows refer to sample f1 from treatment t1, but I am measuring the values for two different things (A and B). So column 5 as found above is calculated thusly:

```
col5
(20-20)
(19-19)
(21-21)
(25-20)
(25-19)
(26-21)
etc...
```

Adding a column is nice and easy, but I am having trouble finding a good way to build in all those conditions. If anyone has a suggestion for how to code this, and/or how to organize my data better to make things easier, I'd be very thankful! Thus far I've just been manually generating column 5's values in MS excel :\

Cheers

Edit2: Answered. Thanks a bunch to all who replied!

Comment: This is really complicated to follow. "and subtract col4's value for col3=="A"" There are 6 values for col3=="A". Are you referring to the average of these 6? what exactly do you mean by this line

Comment: Sorry if it's a bit confusing, I'll try re-writing the question. Thanks for the feedback.

I mean to say that we are interested in the values for f1 B minus f1 A, within the treatment t1. A formula for the output column would likely also take f1A minus f1 A, within treatment t1, which would just be zero. I don't technically need this value, but it's fine if it's there, and is probably a good validation step to ensure the code is working properly anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df[order(df$col1,df$col3,df$col2),]          ## make sure you have it ordered right
flength = length(unique(df$col2))            ## get the length of unique col2
alength = length(unique(df$col3))            ## get the length of unique col3
Avector = df[df$col3=="A","col4"]             ## get the elements of col 4 with col3="A"
sapplyVec = (1:alength) - 1                  ## create vector to sapply over

## take the elements in Avector in sections of size flength and repeat those
## section alength times.
Avector = c(sapply(sapplyVec ,function(x) rep(Avector[c(1:flength)+(x*flength)],alength)))
```

This takes the vector created from the col4 where col3="A". Then it repeats chunks of size flength (3 in your case), alength times (2 in your case). From here you can add the new colums as col4 - Avector

df$col5 = df$col4 - Avector

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just tried this out, and it worked great. Thanks for the ## clarifications too! Awesome. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, if `col3 == "B"`, then you take the matching row where `col3 == "A"` and subtract the corresponding values from `col4`? Then, you need something like this (assuming your data frame is called `df`):

```
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1] {
  if(df[i, 3] == "B") {
    df[i, 5] <- df[i, 4] - df[which(df[1:(i-1), 1] == df[i, 1] & df[1:(i-1),2] == df[i, 2] & df[1:(i-1),3] == "A"), 4]
  }
}
```

Fixed typo in original post.

Comment: Using this sample dataframe... I think it's asking me to define object i?

> for(i in dim(df)[1] {
Error: unexpected '{' in "for(i in dim(df)[1] {"
>   if(df[i, 3] == "B") {
+     df[i, 5] <- df[i, 4] - df[which(df[1:(i-1), 1] == df[i, 1] & df[1:(i-1),2] == df[i, 2] & df[1:(i-1),3] == "A"), 4]
+   }
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, i, 3) : object 'i' not found
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Answer (score 0):

While user2864849's system worked for this example dataframe, upon trying to apply it to my real data, it wound up giving an output with twice the number of values in column 5 as there should have been. I couldn't figure out why, but it was something to do with how it treated the sapply function. Re-visiting the problem, I realized there was a very simple, albeit longer coding solution that would work, with the reminder from user286's code to generate new vectors of the sorted data.

I generated vectors of the values in column 4 for each subset in column 3. I then sorted the dataframe such that it would come out in the same form as the order of my generated vectors. Then I just made a new vector combining these individual vectors to generate column 5. Finally I added column 5 to the sorted dataframe.

```
#Define variables - optional
col1<-as.factor(df$col1)
col2<-as.factor(df$col2)
col3<-as.factor(df$col3)
col4<-df$col4

## Create vectors of Cq values for each gene
col3Avec = df[col3=="A","col4"]  
col3Bvec = df[col3=="B","col4"]

#Create vectors of dCq values of each gene
col5A<-col3Avec-col3Avec
Col5B<-col3Bvec-col3Avec

#Sort dataframe so its order matches the order of the dCq vectors
dfsort <- df[order(col3,col1,col2),]

#Add dCq vectors in correct order as new column to sorted dataframe
dfsort$col5<-c(col5A,col5B)

#Total = 6 lines of codes not including variable definitions
```

Regardless of length, or unequal sample sizes, I think this approach will work out. Looks like a lot of code, but if all variable are named consistently in the data you're applying this code to, there is minimal recoding that needs to be done to apply it.